# Android Studio - Updating activity TextView based on user input from another activity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, page-refresh

This is my first android app and I am creating a very basic Money Manager.

When the app first opens, it opens to a home page where some preloaded data is hardcoded (Purely for test reasons). I have an option for the user to edit these values on another page, however when switching back to the home view the new values are not displayed.

Here is the code. Appreciate any help!

```
// Create New Activity

package com.example.moneymanager;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class CreateNewActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    // Declare Button Variables
    Button dashboardBtn, homeBtn, extrasBtn, cancelBtn, saveBtn;
    EditText projectTitle, goalName;
    Boolean savedFlag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_new_page);

        // Link buttons to xml value
        dashboardBtn = findViewById(R.id.dashboard_btn);
        homeBtn = findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
        extrasBtn = findViewById(R.id.extras_btn);
        cancelBtn = findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.save_btn);

        // Link Edit Text with Id
        projectTitle = findViewById(R.id.name_value);
        goalName = findViewById(R.id.goal1_name_value);

        // Set onClick listener for dashboard btn
        dashboardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                moveToDashboard();
            }
        });

        // Set onClick listener for home btn
        homeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                moveToHome();
            }
        });

        // Set onClick listener for extras btn
        extrasBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                moveToExtras();
            }
        });

        // Listener for cancel Btn
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                moveToHome();
            }
        });

        // Listener for save Btn
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveProject();
                moveToHome();
            }
        });
    }

    /*************************Private Methods*****************************/
    // Create private method for dashboard
    private void moveToDashboard(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    // Create private method for extras
    private void moveToHome(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    // Private method for extras btn
    private void moveToExtras(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ExtrasActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    //Private method for save Btn
    private void saveProject(){
        // Link user Input with defined variables
        projectTitle.getText();
        goalName.getText();

        // Set flag to true to use in main activity
        savedFlag = true;
    }
}




// Main Activity

package com.example.moneymanager;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Declare Button Variables
    Button dashboardBtn, extrasBtn;
    TextView overViewText, savingsGoalText;

    // Create a new instance of the CreateNewActivity Class
    CreateNewActivity retrieve = new CreateNewActivity();
    Boolean savedFlagIsTrue = retrieve.savedFlag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Link NAVIGATION to xml value
        dashboardBtn = findViewById(R.id.dashboard_btn);
        extrasBtn = findViewById(R.id.extras_btn);

        // Set onClick listener for dashboard btn
        dashboardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view){
               moveToDashboard();
           }
        });

        // Set onClick listener for extras btn
        extrasBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                moveToExtras();
            }
        });

        // If user has saved a new project
        if (savedFlagIsTrue){
            String projectTitle = retrieve.projectTitle.toString();
            String goalTitle = retrieve.goalName.toString();

            // Link and set Overview Text with input from CreateNewActivity Class
            overViewText = findViewById(R.id.overview_text);
            overViewText.setText(projectTitle);

            // Link and set Goal Text with input from CreateNewActivity Class
            savingsGoalText = findViewById(R.id.savings_goal_text);
            savingsGoalText.setText(goalTitle);
        }

    }

    // Create private method for dashboard
    private void moveToDashboard(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    // Create private method for extras
    private void moveToExtras(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ExtrasActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, you try to load the entered values in the onCreate-Method of your main activity?
If I am not mistaken, that method will not be called after closing the second activity again (it will only be called after the activity has been stopped or destroyed, but it will only be *paused* when the second activity is started).

---

You might try to look for the user input inside the **onResume**-Method which *should* be called once the activity gets back into the foreground.
It has been a few days since I last worked with Android, so you might want to take a look at the activity lifecylce documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle 
It reads (regarding onResume):

> Such an event might be, for instance, receiving a phone call, the user’s navigating to another activity, or the device screen’s turning off.

That sounds to me like the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that every time you change the activity, you create a new one. So your hardcoded data cannot be taken over and received. I would recommend to look at [this (startActivityForResult())](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Maybe a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide#java) would be another option for you. There you use Fragments instead of activities, but you can do all your stuff with them as well. If you store the Fragments in your PagerAdapter as variables the data will be stored and you can access them via get method or interfaces.

Hope that helps ;)